# NetCore Docker Application with connection refused

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-container, docker-network, kestrel-http-server

I have two containers (both .net-core), a Web Application and a Web API, the Web Application can be accessed from the host machine using http://localhost:51217, however I can't access the Web API using http://localhost:51218, I got the connection refused, in order to access the Web API, I had to change the Kerstel URL configuration from ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost to  ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0, so webserver listen all IP's.

Any clue why the localhost works for the Web App but not for the Web API, although both have different port mapping.

See below my docker-compose working fine, if I change the API to ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost, I will get connection refused. The docker files exposes port 80.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  documentuploaderAPI:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentuploader
    container_name: DocumentUpoaderAPI
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0 
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51217:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
      - c:\azurite:/root/.unistad/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocumentUploader/Dockerfile

  documentmanagerAPP:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentmanager
    container_name: DocumentManagerApp
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51218:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Document Manager/Dockerfile

networks:
  doc_manager:
    name: doc_manager
    driver: bridge
```

Any idea why localhost doesn't work for the API? Any suggestion also how can I trace or sniff the communication from browser until the web server in the container?

You can find below the docker networking design, which may help on my question.

[image: Docker Networking Design]

Comment: Your server URLs are weird and don't follow the syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#server-urls. The first one should be `http://*:80` and the second one should be `http://*:80` as well. There's no need to have it listen for https since you don't map a port for it. I'm surprised that localhost works for you, since that means it should only accept requests coming from the container itself.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I updated the docker-compose. This localhost behavior is really weird. I believe .net-core / kestrel is doing something behind the scenes. Just in case you can help me with another similar question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253202/docker-container-connection-refused)